# Expiry Meta data for a S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my C# code, I am setting the retention date for a S3 object. I want to check if the retention date that I set in C# is right so Is there any way to check in the management console what the retention date has been set to for a particular object. This is what I tried to do

1. I went to the Management console
2. clicked on s3 Bucket
3. selected my test Object
4. selected edit Meta data from properties.

here I can set the expiry date for the object inside S3 bucket, but I am trying to see the Object Lock retention date that I set through my C# code. This is the screen, I see when I go to Edit MetaData:

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it would appear in the Metadata? Based on [Configuring S3 Object Lock using the console - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock-console.html), it seems that the information would be in the **Object overview** screen.